# Componente é renderizado novamente sempre que estado de algum input é alterado

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks, componentes, react-dom

Bom dia galera. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde o registro do usuário é de acordo com a opção que o mesmo seleciona " Fisica ou Juridica ". De acordo com a opção que ele escolhe um form é renderizado através de functions / component, o problema é que renderizando dessa forma sempre que altero o valor de algum input, ou seja, algum Estado a pagina da um refresh. Como eu poderia tirar esse problema ?

registro.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import './register-style.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css'; 
import api from '../../services/api';

export default function Registro() {
  const [tipo, setTipo] = useState('');
  const [nomerazao, setNomeRazao] = useState('');
  const [cpfcnpj, setCpfCnpj] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [sexo, setSexo] = useState('');
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('A');
  const [endereco, setEndereco] = useState('');
  const [nroendereco, setNroEndereco] = useState('');
  const [bairro, setBairro] = useState('');
  const [cidade, setCidade] = useState('');
  const [uf, setUf] = useState('');
  const [cep, setCep] = useState('');
  const [ddd, setDdd] = useState('');
  const [telefone, setTelefone] = useState('');

  function CNPJ() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>

          <input 
            placeholder="Insira sua Razão Social"
            value={nomerazao}
            onChange={e => setNomeRazao(e.target.value)}
          />

          <input 
            placeholder="Insira seu CNPJ"
            value={cpfcnpj}
            onChange={e => setCpfCnpj(e.target.value)}
          />

          <input 
            type="email" 
            placeholder="Insira seu email"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />

          <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
    );
  };

  function CPF() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>

          <input 
            placeholder="Insira seu Nome"
            value={nomerazao}
            onChange={e => setNomeRazao(e.target.value)}
          />

          <input 
            placeholder="Insira seu CPF"
            value={cpfcnpj}
            onChange={e => setCpfCnpj(e.target.value)}
          />

          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Insira sua senha"
            value={password}
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          

          <input 
            type="email" 
            placeholder="Insira seu email"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />

          <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
    );
  };

  function Form (){

    if(tipo === '') {
      return (
        <div>
          <span>Selecione um tipo de cadastro...</span>
        </div>
      )
    }else if(tipo === 'F') {
      return (
        <div>
          <CPF />
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <CNPJ />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="formulario">

    <h1>Registro</h1>

    <div className="botoes">
      <span>Tipo de cadastro: </span>
      <select value={tipo} onChange={e => setTipo(e.target.value)}>
        <option disabled value="">Selecione</option>
        <option value="F">Usuário</option>
        <option value="J">Empresa</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <Form />

    <Link to="/">Voltar ao Login</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Função handleRegister:

```js
async function handleRegister(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = ({
      
    });

    try{
      await api.post('/pessoa/register', data)
          .then(function(response){
              if(response.status === 200){
                  toast.success(`${response.data.name} Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso !`);
                  // setTimeout(() =>{
                  //     history.push('/')
                  // }, 3250);
              }
          });
    } catch (err) {
      if(err.response.status === 400) {
          toast.error(err.response.data.error);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: " *a pagina da um refresh* " -> a página atualiza ou o componente `Registro` renderiza novamente?

Comment: Exato Rafael, o componente renderiza novamente. Vou alterar até o titulo, peço perdão pelo equivoco.

Comment: Esse é o comportamento esperado. Um componente renderiza quando há mudança de estado. Se todos inputs são controlados (com `useState`) no mesmo componente, a mudança de estado do input `A` causará a renderização do componente inteiro.

Comment: O que acontece é que seu `<Form />` poderia ser um componente diferente, visto que a sua página inteira parece ser um componente apenas. Fora isso, não vejo problemas. Se o `<Form />` possuísse componentes filhos, alguns outros métodos poderiam ser utilizados para evitar a renderização dos filhos, veja essa pergunta para mais detalhes: [Como usar “shouldComponentUpdate” com Hooks?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447861/100416)

Comment: No caso você acredita que se eu criar apenas um componente e juntar tudo em um só resolveria meu problema ?

Comment: Me confundi por causa do `Link` no componente. Se `Registro` representa apenas o formulário para registro, tudo bem, não precisa componentizar mais. É questão de opinião, e é difícil opinar sem ter o contexto. Recomendo a leitura da documentação do React para tentar entender o que significa um componente e consequentemente quando componentizar. PS: Não tem problemas no código de `Registro`, não terá problemas de desempenho pois é um componente muito simples **hoje**.

Comment: A questão é que, se eu coloco qualquer um desses forms no " return () " padrão do react lá em baixo, eu consigo digitar normal nos inputs sem nenhum refresh ou reload de componente. Meu problema está sendo só no fato de renderizar o form pelo componente, pois sempre esta atualizando. E, caso eu tire os ```onChange``` dos inputs mesmo no componente eu consigo digitar normal sem que ele fique renderizando toda hora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113644/discussion-between-rafael-tavares-and-leo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize com componente e a função [memo](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) que previne esse reenderização:

```js
const Email = React.memo(({value, setValue}) => {  
  return (
    <div>   
      <div style={{height: 20}}>{value}</div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  )
});

const Password = React.memo(({value, setValue}) => {  
  return (
    <div>      
      <div style={{height: 20}}>{value}</div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  )
});



function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');  
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');   
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('App Input Renderização');
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Email value={email} setValue={setEmail} />
      <Password  value={password} setValue={setPassword} />  
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

***Explicação no próprio site***: [Se seu componente renderiza o mesmo resultado dados os mesmos props, você pode envolver nele uma chamada para React.memo para um aumento no desempenho em alguns casos, através da memoização do resultado. Isto significa que o React vai pular a renderização do componente e reutilizar o último resultado renderizado.](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)